Apply image transformations on Geotiff in c#
I have a Geotiff file and I want to overlay it on a map. For display of the map I am using the GMapControl from GNet. To overlay the image I am using a GMapMarker that I defined and I pass there as Source the BitmapImage.
I want to apply some transformations to my image like rotations, scaling and translation to overlay it on the map. Is it possible to know how to calculate the values to apply rotation, scaling and translation using the Geotransform?
This is a part of the code that I am using and as you can see I have fixed values in the three parameters that I want to use to transform the image (RotateTransform, ScaleTransform and TranslateTransform).
How can I calculate the correct value to put on these three, using the metadata that comes from the geotransform?
_marker = new GMapMarker(new PointLatLng(topLeftY, topLeftX))
{
    // Set the size of the marker
    Shape = new System.Windows.Controls.Image
    {
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("teste.tif")),
        Width = 100,
        Height = 100,
        
        RenderTransform = new TransformGroup
        {
            Children = new TransformCollection
            {
                new RotateTransform(rotationAngle), // Apply rotation
                new ScaleTransform(1, -1), 
                new TranslateTransform(0.5, -1)
            }
        }
    }
};

I try using GdalWarp and OpenCv, but it seems that the C# doesn't have a lot of support for using the GdalWarp function, my application keeps getting stuck when i try to use that function.
For OpenCv, my application also keeps getting stuck when I try to read the geotif file because native opencv doesn't support geotif files. I didn't want to transform the file into a png file. So now I am trying to use these three parameters that GMapMarker allows me to use, but i need to know what values should I apply.
Thank you for any help that you can give!

from the tutorial on GDAL (https://gdal.org/en/latest/tutorials/geotransforms_tut.html) I assume the parameters are already contained in the geotransform.

Thank you @MakePeaceGreatAgain for your comment! But those parameters don't give me the correct values to use in  ScaleTransform and TranslateTransform. If I am not mistaken I have to calculate the two values from ScaleTransform through the geotransform values?
